# Constructor parameter style

Tags: c++, methods, parameters, reference, constructor

Lets say my file looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class testclass{
public: string name;
        //testclass(const string& sref){
          //  name = sref;
        //}
        testclass(string str){
            name = str;
        }
        ~testclass(){}
};

int main(){
    testclass t1("constStringRef");
    cout << t1.name << '\n';
}
```

What are the differences between constructor 1 and 2 given the following constructor-call:

```
testclass tobj("tmemberstring");
```

Here is what i thought of:

I know that passing by reference means that you don't pass a copy but due to the string-argument there is a string-initialization at first (in both cases treated like a local variable, i assume), which is then followed by a the initialization of a reference to it in case 1 or a copy to a new string str in case 2. In the end both of the constructors copy the values to the member string name. If my thoughts are correct i would skip one step (copying into string str) if would use the first constructor.

Sidequestions:
Are arguments stored in the stack area?
And if so how much space would this particular string reference or a reference to any basic data types use?

Hoping for your advice,
thanks in advance

Comment: Everything in your code makes no sense. what are `n` and `s`?!

Comment: You should try to compile you code before bloating it onto StackOverflow!

Comment: Sorry renamed it to make it clearer and forgot to rename the assignments.

Comment: Do neither; if you're going to store a copy of the string in your class, accept the argument by value and then `std::move` it *in the constructor's initializer list*.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preferred parameter passing for constructors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7650769/preferred-parameter-passing-for-constructors)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to answer your question is to break down what happens in both cases.

## `testclass(const string& sref)`

- `testclass t1("constStringRef");` first creates a temporary `string` object from the `const char*`
- the constructor is called, the temporary `string` object is bound to the constructor's `const string&` argument
- `name` is uselessly default-constructed since you didn't use the constructor's initializer list (*more on that later*)
- `string::operator =` is called, making a copy of the `const string&` argument

**Total:** 1 copy.

## `testclass(string str)`

- `testclass t1("constStringRef");` first creates a temporary `string` object from the `const char*`
- the constructor is called -- what happens depend on which C++ version you are using:

  - C++03: the temporary `string` object is copied to the constructor's argument
  - C++11: the temporary is *moved* into the constructor's argument
- `name` is uselessly default-constructed since you didn't use the constructor's initializer list
- `string::operator =` is called, making a copy of the `string` argument

**Total:** 2 copies in C++03, 1 copy in C++11.

---

From this, we could believe that a `const string&` is better. However **this is only true in C++03**.

---

## C++11 and move semantics

In C++11, it is better (in this very case) to pass the string by value to the constructor, and then move the argument into your class member:

```
    testclass(string str){
        name = std::move(str);
    }
```

Let's see what happens now:

- `testclass t1("constStringRef");` first creates a temporary `string` object from the `const char*`
- the constructor is called, the temporary is *moved* into the constructor's argument
- `name` is uselessly default-constructed since you didn't use the constructor's initializer list
- `string::operator =` is called, but this time *moving* the `string` argument into `name`

**Total:** 0 copy!

---

This is all fine with rvalues, but does this still hold true for lvalues?

```
string s = "..."; // s has already been constructed some time ago
testclass t1(s);  // what happens during this call?
```

- **for a constructor that takes `const string&`** (both in C++03 and C++11):

  - `s` is bound to the `const string&` argument
  - `name` is uselessly default-constructed since you didn't use the constructor's initializer list
  - `string::operator =` is called, making a copy of the `const string&` argument
  - **Total:** 1 copy.
- **for a constructor that takes `string` and then moves it** (only in C++11):

  - `s` is copied to the `string` argument
  - `name` is uselessly default-constructed since you didn't use the constructor's initializer list
  - `string::operator =` is called, but this time *moving* the `string` argument into `name`
  - **Total:** 1 copy.

## Wrapping it up

**In C++03**, whether you're passing a lvalue or a rvalue doesn't matter, it is always more efficient to use a `const string&`. As others have mentioned, you may want to overload your constructor to take a `const char*` argument and thus avoid a useless copy.

**In C++11**, provided you move the argument into the member variable, a `string` argument is the same as a `const string&` argument for lvalues, but it is more efficient for rvalues (no copy needs to be performed at all). So you should use pass-by-value and then move the argument to the member variable.

---

Last but not least, you noticed that I insisted on uselessly default-constructing `name`. To avoid it, use the constructor's initializer list rather than an assignment in the constructor's body:

```
    // C++03
    testclass(const char* str) : name(str) {}       // no copy
    testclass(const string& sref) : name(sref) {}   // 1 copy

    // C++11
    testclass(string str) : name(std::move(str)) {} // 1 copy for lvalues,
                                                    // no copy for rvalues
```

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, the constructor accepts a `std::string`.  Since you are calling the constructor with a string literal (a `const char*`), a temporary `std::string` is going to be constructed in order to call the constructor.  The difference between the two methods is what happens next:

In the case of `testclass(const string& sref)` a `const` reference to the temporary `string` you just created can be taken.  In the second case, the string is taken by value, so a *second* temporary needs+ to be created.

- note:  compilers can sometimes optimize this second temporary away.

As a general rule of thumb, I would suggest using the `const&` whenever possible.

Note however, that you could avoid constructing the temporary `std::string` altogether, by simply accepting string literals via a template:

```
template <size_t N> testclass(const char (&str)[N])
{
  name = str;
}
```

Note also, that when your constructor is called two things happen. 1) The `name` member is constructed. 2) The value of the `name` member is changed.  You can initialize and construct the `name` member in a single step, using an initialization list:

```
template <size_t N> testclass(const char (&str)[N])
: 
  name (str, N-1)  // minus one to not copy the trailing `\0`.  Optional, depending
{
  name = str;
}
```

Comment: `template <size_t N> testclass(const char* (&str)[N])` => This is quite wrong. Here you're taking an `array[N]` of `const char*`. Either take just a `const char*`, or a `const char (&str)[N]`. Obviously just a `const char*` is preferable because arrays can decay to pointers, while pointers can't be promoted to fixed-length arrays. Also, why the initialization + assignment?

Comment: @syam:  Thanks for pointing that out.  That's what I get for not compiling.

Answer (score 0):

First of alle, better finish your stream lines with "std::endl" not "'\n'". 
One Constructor expects a reference, the other one a value, but you are passing a C-String which is of value "const char*".
Third of all: initialize your member before calling the Constructor-Code.
I would recommend the following;

```
testclass(const char* name) : name(name) {};
```

Comment: `cout` is typically line buffered, in which case `endl` vs. `\n` doesn't make any difference.

Comment: @Praetorian: But still, why would forcing a flush be the better advice?

Comment: yes i know that i passed a c-string but due to the conversion constructor of string this shouldn't matter. correct me if i'm wrong and thanks for your info on initializing.

Answer (score 0):

> I know that passing by reference means that you don't pass a copy

That's right, so you should normally prefer `testclass::testclass(const std::string&)`, because it avoids that copy

> but due to the string-argument there is a string-initialization at first

yes, there is either a temporary string created and passed as a const ref, or the argument is created directly.

There's another string though: your `name` member is default initialized only because you didn't use the initializer list. This:

```
testclass::testclass(const std::string &s) : name(s) {}
```

initializes `name` *directly*, without first default-initializing it and then changing it in the constructor body.

---

> Sidequestions: Are arguments stored in the stack area?

arguments could be held on stack, or in registers, or in any other way a compiler finds that complies with the standard. This is an implementation detail.

> ...  And if so how much space would this particular string reference or a reference to any basic data types use?

In general, a reference is probably *at most* the size of a pointer (and might be elided entirely).

The thing you haven't considered is that `std::string` owns a dynamically-allocated copy of your character array, so every `std::string` you pass by value may perform a dynamic allocation, and then a de-allocation when it goes out of scope. (Some compilers may avoid this with reference-counting, but we're back on implementation details).